# Call script through subproce.Popen without blocking explanation needed

Tags: subprocess, tornado

Basically this code reads from a pipe and constantly prints output without blocking ... Here is the whole code:

1)First script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        print str(i)+'\n',
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
```

2) Second script:

```
def log_worker(stdout):

    while True:
        output = non_block_read(stdout).strip()
        if output:
            print output


def non_block_read(output):
    ''' even in a thread, a normal read with block until the buffer is full '''
    fd = output.fileno()
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        return output.read()
    except:
        return ''

if __name__ == '__main__':

    mysql_process = subprocess.Popen(['python','-u', 'flush.py'],  stdin=sys.stdin,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


    thread = Thread(target=log_worker, args=[mysql_process.stdout])
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    mysql_process.wait()
    thread.join(timeout=1)
```

*I would like to know why it works that way :*

**1)** If i take Thread absolutely away , and just call log_worker in the main at also prints everything one by one , but the problem is it hangs after completion without finishing. And i read somewhere that here thread is exactly used for it to finish or more correctly thread dies when it finishes printing something , So why does it work that way ? What thread exactly does here and how ?

**2)** If i keep the thread but remove mysql_process.wait() and thread.join it prints nothing .... Why ?   I read that Popen.wait is meant for its child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.    What is the child process here and why/how it is child O_O ?

**3)** If i only remove  thread.join(timeout=1) then it finishes but with error `Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):`. Why ? What role .join plays here.

**4)** I read the documentation of functions used in non_block_read function , but still am confused. Okay it is obvious they take file descriptor and set it to non blocking .  The thing i am confused is , on what can i use all those functions , i mean i understand that on files , but how come they use it on stdout O_O ?  It's not a file , it's a stream ~~ ?

All this i do to execute a script with subprocess.Popen in tornado script , and constantly send output to client/myself without blocking, so if anyone can kind of help me do that  i would really appreciate it , because i can't imagine how to kind of get this output from thread in a way that i can constanly insert it in self.send  in tornadio2 ...

```
def on_message(self, message):
#        list = subprocess.Popen([r"ls", "-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#        list_stdout = list.communicate()[0]
        for i in range(1,10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.send(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the dev version (3.2), that's realy easy

```
from tornado.web import RequestHandler,asynchronous
from tornado.process import Subprocess

class home(RequestHandler):
  @asynchrounous
  def get(self):
    seld.sp=Subprocess('date && sleep 5 && date',shell=True,stdout=Subprocess.STREAM)
    self.sp.set_exit_callback(self.next)
  def next(self,s):
    self.sp.stdout.read_until_close(self.finish)

application = ...
```